# STH-Comet installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-sth-comet

Recently I installed in a Fiware instance STH-Comet through the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet.git
cd fiware-sth-comet
npm install
```

Today I went to install again and when cloning the STH-Comet repository the following error arose:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /etc/fiware-sth-comet/.git/
>   error:  while accessing https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet.git/info/refs
>   fatal: HTTP request failed**

Have there been any changes to the STH-Comet repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, it is due a permission denied. Try to set up your public key on github. Instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ and check it again. There were no changes in that repository.

Comment: Is the Fiware repository not public?

The first time I installed STH-Comet, I didn't need it. I just ran the command and downloaded it on my instance.

Even in windows clone without the need to generate SSH key. This problem only happened in CentOS of my instance.

Comment: Which is the version of git that you are using? The repository is public.

Comment: Git Version 1.7.1

Comment: I was able to clone by changing https:// for git:// and the installation was successful.
Thanks!